# Нужна помощь с оптимизацией кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Помогите оптимизировать код:

```
line = input()
n = int(input())
r = []
line1 =''
line1 = line
for i in range(n):
    [n1, n2] = map(int, input().split())
    line1 = line1[0:n1-1] + line1[n1-1:n2].swapcase() + line1[n2:len(line)]
print(line1)
```

Ограничение по времени - 1сек., а у меня выполняется за 1.091сек.

---

Задание:

> B. Инвертирование Ограничение времени 1 секунда Ограничение
>   памяти    64Mb Ввод   стандартный ввод или input.txt Вывод    стандартный
>   вывод или output.txt Дана строка S и Q запросов. Запрос представляет
>   собой пару чисел L и R — промежуток строки S, на котором нужно
>   инвертировать регистр символов. Требутеся найти строку S после
>   выполнения всех запросов.
>
> Формат ввода В первой строке задается строка S, состоящая из строчных
>   и прописных букв латинского алфавита (1 ≤ |S| ≤ 105).
>
> Во второй строке задается число Q — количество запросов (0 ≤ Q ≤ 106).
>
> В следующих Q строках задаются запросы парой целых чисел Li Ri (1 ≤ Li
>   ≤ Ri ≤ N).
>
> Формат вывода Выведите строку S после выполнения всех запросов.
>
> Пример
>
> Стандартный ввод:
>
> ```
> aNDERSenProgrAmmIngContest
> 10
> 1 5
> 5 9
> 11 16
> 11 13
> 15 16
> 15 19
> 15 16
> 18 19
> 5 6
> 6 9
> ```
>
> Стандартный вывод:
>
> ```
> AndersenProgrammingContest
> ```

Comment: что конкретно вы хотите оптимизировать? У вас скорость работы программы главным образом зависит от того, насколько быстро пользователь будет вводить данные.

Comment: Извините за англ. Я решаю тесты и там input производится роботом, и счет начинается от выполнения задачи, Time Limit в этом задании 1сек.,а у меня выполняется за 1.091сек.)

Comment: Понял, ну а нет никаких решений для оптимизации?

Comment: время, наверное, набирается на постоянной перестройке строки. может, какую-нить сделать шкалу на длину строки и там переворачивать true/false, а потом один раз менять регистр строке?

Answer (score 2):

```
line = input()
n = int(input())
r = []

buffer = list(line)

for i in range(n):
    [n1, n2] = map(int, input().split())
    for j in range(n1, n2):
        buffer[j] = buffer[j].swapcase()

print(''.join(buffer))
```

Вот так должно быть быстрее - здесь не происходит многократное пересоздание строки.

Comment: Нет, этот код уже после 3-го теста показывает 1.087, в то время как тот код после 9 теста показывал 1.091

Answer (score 1):

Для начала представим отрезки в более подходящем виде:

Начало отрезка - индекс символа, начиная с которого инвертируем регистр
Конец отрезка - индекс символа, начиная с которого перестаем инвертировать

Т.е. просто уменьшаем первое значение каждой пары на единицу

```
[0;5), [4;9), [10;16), [10;13), [14;16), [14;19), [14;16), [17;19), [4;6), [5;9)
```

Так как дважды инвертированный участок возвращается к первоначальному виду, получается, в начале и в конце каждого отрезка мы меняем поведение на противоположное: если до этого момента мы инвертировали регистр, то перестаем и наоборот.

Теперь отсортировав все значения (начала и концы отрезков вместе) получаем

```
0 - инвертируем
4 - не инвертируем
4 - инвертируем
5 - не инвертируем
5 - инвертируем
6 - не инвертируем
9 - инвертируем
9 - не инвертируем
10 - инвертируем
10 - не инвертируем
13 - инвертируем
14 - не инвертируем
14 - инвертируем
14 - не инвертируем
16 - инвертируем
16 - не инвертируем
16 - инвертируем
17 - не инвертируем
19 - инвертируем
19 - не инвертируем
```

Лишние индексы можно выкинуть: например `4`, `5`, `9`, `10`, `19` повторяются четное количество раз, значит вообще не влияют на результат.
А `14` и `16`, которые повторяются по три раза, достаточно учесть всего один раз.

Итого

```
0 - инвертируем
6 - не инвертируем
13 - инвертируем
14 - не инвертируем
16 - инвертируем
17 - не инвертируем
```

Получение конечного результата будет выглядеть примерно так (разумеется, будет нужен цикл)

```
result = []
result.append(line[:0]) # До первого измененного участка (тут это пустая строка)
result.append(line[0:6].swapcase())
result.append(line[6:13])
result.append(line[13:14].swapcase())
result.append(line[14:16])
result.append(line[16:17].swapcase())
result.append(line[17:]) # До конца (инвертируем если требуется)
print(''.join(result))
```

Comment: Неплохо было бы увидеть реализацию.

Comment: @insolor Не в моих правилах выкладывать готовые решения олимпиадных задач, но могу вас заверить, что программа на python, написанная по этому алгоритму, укладывается во все ограничения задачи. Так как количество запросов потенциально больше длины строки (я описывал алгоритм не учитывая это), можно использовать сортировку подсчетом, и не заморачиваться с группировкой индексов, а обрабатывать строку посимвольно как у вас, так как это незначительно повлияет на время.

Answer (score 0):

Постоянное разбиение и соединение строк - это довольно медленная операция.

Вариант, предложенный участником [**splash58**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180637): сначала для каждого символа строки рассчитываем, нужно ли его регистр инвертировать, потом уже по этим данным формируем готовую строку.

```
line = input()

# В этом списке будет записано, нужно ли инвертировать символ (True) или нет (False):
swap_case = [False] * len(line)

n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    start, end = map(int, input().split())
    for j in range(start-1, end):
        swap_case[j] = not swap_case[j]

result = ''.join(c.swapcase() if swap else c for c, swap in zip(line, swap_case))

# Этот однострочник примерно соответствует такому циклу:

# result = []
# for c, swap in zip(line, swap_case):
#     if swap:
#         result.append(c.swapcase())
#     else:
#         result.append(c)

# result = ''.join(result)

print(result)
```

Comment: Это все еще `O(|S| * Q)` в худшем случае, оптимальное решение отработает за `O(|S| + Q)` и уложится на таком тесте в одну секунду. `print('a' * 100000, 1000000, *["1 100000"] * 1000000, sep='\n', file=open('input.txt', 'w'))`